# BCP not copying

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm running a simple bcp query from Windows 2008/SQL 2008 command line, but the data is not copying.  The issue may be quotations missing in the second statement but I've tried a few different ways and no luck.  I run a few SET statements to cover the variables before hand.

This works:

bcp "SELECT * FROM FS84RPT.dbo.PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE WHERE FISCAL_YEAR = 2015" queryout %OUTPUT%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.txt -e %ERRORLOG%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.err -o %TIMINGS%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.txt -T -c

This doesn’t work below (I added an extra qualifier)

bcp "SELECT * FROM FS84RPT.dbo.PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE WHERE FISCAL_YEAR = 2015 AND ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 9" queryout %OUTPUT%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.txt -e %ERRORLOG%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.err -o %TIMINGS%\PS_CM_ACCTG_LINE.txt -T -c

The above does not copy any rows.  Appreciate input

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you sure the query actually returns any records? Are you getting any errors when running the BCP command, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: actually you were right on your comment...I was quering data from two separate databases and didn't realize until later that one was missing data.  All is good.